# How can I detect if the display was powered down by dpms?

Tags: power-management

Assuming I power down my laptop display with:

```
vbetool dpms off
# or
xset dpms force off
```

how can I detect that the display is now off?

I would like to switch between on and off with a single button so I need to know the current state.

**Is there any way to directly get the current state or do I really have to track changes?**

Tracking changes is a bit more complicated then you may expect as these changes can by triggered by *vbetool, xset, gnome-power-manager, ...*

---

**Update:** I'm on a Lenovo W530 with display: `B156HW01`

Comment: `ddccontrol -p` ? If the monitor is off it will show limited info. Otherwise it will show all kinds of info.

Comment: @Rinzwind `ddccontrol -p` fails with `I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/usr/share/ddccontrol-db/monitor/LEN40B2.xml"` and `Detected monitors : - Device: dev:/dev/i2c-14, DDC/CI supported: No, Monitor Name: VESA standard monitor, Input type: Digital, No monitor supporting DDC/CI available.` - independent of display state, I added my display model to the question, am I missing some kernel modules for this or does my display just not support DDC/CI ?

Comment: `DDC/CI supported: No` is  a problem, that won't work :(